# Can the stability of higher order Sigma-Delta Modulator be relaxed with higher level ADC?

Tags: adc

I have been studying about the Sigma-Delta modulators having multi-bit ADC  (with low OSR) instead of single-bit ADC (high OSR). We see an improvement in terms of stability. I just want to know if we keep increasing the number of bits of ADC (like 6-7 bits), can a stable 5th or 6th order Sigma-Delta ADC be realized? (serving an increased bandwidth)

Comment: In theory yes but cost from complexity rise is quadratic

Comment: @ Tony The DAC is costly?

Comment: There are excellent papers by Malcolm (Omar) Hawksford of the University of Essex covering this topic - as published in the JAES (Journal of the Audio Engineering Society) in the late 80s to mid 1990s. A good search engine should let you find them.